# Docker: Unable to access container's internal IP from host

Tags: docker

I'm trying to access the container by it's IP address which is 172.17.0.2 (ip from the default network bridge) from the host but it doesn't work, but accessing localhost:4200 works fine. I'm running docker 4.5.1 in windows with WSL2

Build command:

```
docker build -t app .
```

Run command:

```
docker run -it -p 4200:4200 --name app app
```

Docker file:

```
FROM node
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

Comment: there's often a configuration/startup argument that tell the server to listen to all ip address(0.0.0.0) instead of localhost(by default)

Comment: I edited the post and added the docker file, I am already running that command to listen to all IPs

Comment: can you successfully ping the wsl ip from host?

Comment: Yes, the wsl IP is 172.31.137.137 and ping works from host.

Answer (score 3):

The docker bridge network is not reachable that way on Windows. It only works on a Linux host. Which is why it's also considered a bad thing to do.

Access it using the exposed port on localhost:4200

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is there no way of doing it?

Comment: Not to my knowledge

Comment: @ciuz99best I'm interested in what you're trying to accomplish, if mapping the port isn't a good solution.

Comment: The container-private IPs are inaccessible on MacOS, or on Windows, or from a different host, or if you're using Minikube or Docker Toolbox to run Docker in a VM, or ....  I'd go further than @HansKilian and suggest it's not even necessary to look up the container's IP address; it is an internal implementation detail you never need to know.